# How to separate <v-navigation-drawer> in vuetify vue.js app?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuetify.js

I'm trying to create a component out of my app's `<v-navigation-drawer>`, and I'm seeing an error:

> `Unknown custom element: <app-navigation-drawer> - did you register the component correctly? For recursive components, make sure to provide the "name" option.`

Being new to vue.js, I've figured out components to be used within a specific `route`, but can't figure out using a custom component in the main `App.vue` file.

I've tried `importing` and adding it as a `component` in the Vue instance, I've also tried `importing` it within `App.vue` and exporting a default component with that as a component.

**Q**: Can someone please help me understand where I would need to register this component, or what I'm doing wrong?

**App.vue**

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <v-app>
      <app-navigation-drawer/>

      </v-toolbar>
      <v-content>
        <v-container class="grey lighten-5" fluid="fluid" fill-height="fill-height">
          <router-view></router-view>
        </v-container>
      </v-content>
    </v-app>
  </div>
</template>
```

**main.js**

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import App from './App.vue';
import router from './router';
import store from './store';
import Vuetify from 'vuetify';

import NavigationDrawer from './views/NavigationDrawer.vue';
Vue.use(Vuetify);
new Vue({
  router,
  store,
  components: { NavigationDrawer },
  render: h => h(App)
}).$mount('#app');
```

**NavigationDrawer.vue**

```
<template>
    <v-navigation-drawer app stateless value="true">Drawer</v-navigation-drawer>
</template>
<script>
export default {
    name: 'app-navigation-drawer'
}
</script>
```

Comment: @Sphinx it logs the component as expected, so not undefined. I'm not sure if it's a `vue.js` issue, or some quirk/requirement with `vuetify`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is recomended you declare your component like this:

```
components: { 'app-navigation-drawer': NavigationDrawer }
```

That should work.

If you want to do it directly, use the name as declared:

```
<NavigationDrawer></NavigationDrawer>
```

Reference: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-registration.html

Comment: Oh, sorry. You are doing the declaration in the main.js file. You should do it in the App.vue file. Add a script section and declare the component there.